# Add Chocolate for Taste

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking, english, acrostic

Today I have another puzzle for the community. I will warn that some of the hints are obvious while others are not. You'll need a bit of lateral thinking to complete this one! I hope you all enjoy it; and good luck to everyone!

---

> Let's take a journey, an excursion well known; pay close attention, don't fall down the road.
>
> The weather is crisp, invigorating and fresh; it'll help keep us calm, as we recover from stress.
>
> First stop the river, at the rim of the coast; but we need money, for the marshmallow roast.
>
> Grab the horse shoes, a game of pure skill; and listen to the creatures, croaking a will.
>
> Gather by the fire, it's time for the roast; hand me that pamphlet, with stories of ghosts.
>
> The ranger is posted, in his private shack; remember the tallboy, out in the back.

---

**Hint**: Maybe it was unfair of me to not reveal how to solve this puzzle since it is in two parts?

> Each line carries a striking resemblance, yet a subtle difference.

**Hint**: Line six is rather difficult.

> The word which you seek, is where the ranger sits; synonyms for tallboy, find me one that fits.

Comment: Hmm where is the acrostic? :)

Comment: Good observation @QuantumTwinkie :)

Comment: While you're at it, which hints are obvious??

Comment: I think @Stidgeon should get credit, they figured out most of it!

Comment: @SteveV I will be awarding Stidgeon a bounty on this one due to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my addition

As pointed out by @Stidgen

> TRIP is indicated in the first line, a journey or a fall

@TwoBitOperation added

> COOL for the second line, weather and cool down

@TwoBitOperation also added

> BANK for the third line, river side and money place

I think the fourth line is

> FROG because frog can be a horse shoe or a croaker

The fifth line as given by @Stidgen

> CIRCULAR,  round and pamphlet

The sixth line is

> third try:  CABINET, a cabinet post for a ranger perhaps as well as a chest of drawers

The acrostic is

> TONGUE as @Stidgen found!  Well done!  As he points out, please add chocolate.
>  **T**rip
>  c**O**ol
>  ba**N**k
>  fro**G**
>  circ**U**lar
>  cabin**E**t

Comment: +1! Lines 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 are correct. Line 6 is not and the acrostic is not a basic acrostic. Lateral thinking will be required.

Comment: @PerpetualJ Added a new guess for 6

Comment: Still incorrect for line 6. You're heading in the right direction though! Especially the second half there.

Comment: @PerpetualJ ok, this one makes more sense

Comment: Nice one on the last clue!

Answer (score 5):

Possible solution...

I think the first two lines refer to:

> trip, with two different meanings.

Second line refers to:

> chill, again from two meanings.

Fifth line could be:

> circular - a circle around the fire, and a pamphlet

NEW EDIT:
Building on @TwoBitOperation's summary:

> In order, line answers are Trip, cOol, baNk, froGs, circUlar, bottlE. Take the letter corresponding to each line number (as capitalized) to get a diagonal acrostic TONGUE ... Just add chocolate to taste.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! You're correct in that this is referred to by the first line. +1

Comment: Since you've edited your post, your main answer is wrong. You'll have to figure out each line before you can find the main answer.

Comment: The first and fifth lines are correct the second line is really close.

Comment: Well done there Stidgeon! However, the word for line 6 is still incorrect though you've found the acrostic in the intended way! Good find!

Comment: I thought that, too, @Stidgeon, but rot13(V pna'g frr jul n enatre or nffbpvngrq jvgu n qerffre)

Comment: @Stidgeon Your rot13 comment is incredibly close! Look for synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

From @Stidgeon's work, we know each line refers to

> a word with two meanings:

Line 1:

> Trip  (An excursion or a fall)

Line 2:

> Cool (Chilly or Calm)

Line 3:

> Bank  (River-side or Money-holder)

Line 4:

> Cricket (A game of skill or A noisy creature)

Line 5:

> Circular (Round or a Pamphlet)

Line 6:

> Post (A base of operations or A support for beds/furniture)

This gives the acrostic

> TCBCCP

which probably means I'm wrong.  But hopefully this helps someone else!

Comment: Lines 1, 2, 3, and 5 are correct. The acrostic isn't a basic one and requires lateral thinking once all 6 lines have been correctly found.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a

> camping trip?

Let's take a journey, an excursion well known; pay close attention, don't fall down the road.

> A camping trip is a journey, and an excursion.

The weather is crisp, invigorating and fresh; it'll help keep us calm, as we recover from stress.

> A camping trip is usually about nature and relaxation.

First stop the river, at the rim of the coast; but we need money, for the marshmallow roast.

> I don't understand the first half, but of course there's marshmallows.

Grab the horse shoes, a game of pure skill; and listen to the creatures, croaking a will.

> Literal sentence. [Listen to the animals, and let's play horseshoes.]

Gather by the fire, it's time for the roast; hand me that pamphlet, with stories of ghosts.

> Storytime by the fire.

The ranger is posted, in his private shack; remember the tallboy, out in the back.

> I used a [dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=ranger%20definition&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS808US808&oq=ranger%20def&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4205j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on#dobs=tallboy). Basically, campers in a tent, large can of beer at the back. [I think]

Comment: Note that excursion means "a short journey or trip, especially one engaged in as a leisure activity" based on Google.

Comment: It is not a camping trip but this was really neat answer. +1